# Resources for increased complexity in writing

Tags: discussion

I have recently purchased a book called ["The Describer's Dictionary : A Treasury of Terms & Literary Quotations"](https://www.bookdepository.com/Describers-Dictionary-David-Grambs/9780393346169)

It's an incredible book, but it's about "things" rather than, other words. Yes, I know that there is a thing called a thesaurus, but I also know that thesauruses have very general words.

**Does anyone know of websites, books, forums, YouTube channels... Any type of resource that provides synonyms that are complex and involve more than one word?**

I have been looking for a long time and generally all I can find is 1 or 2 posts every now and then for very specific words.
Any help would be really great.

Comment: You seem to want to swim against the tide of *Plain English* and it occurs to me that a search for that term will unearth resources that less brave individuals would use for floating with the tide, and which you might use subversively.  So where, for example, a *Plain English Style Guide* might advocate *use* rather than *utilise* you could go the other way.

Comment: Lots of thesauruses include phrasal verbs, idioms and other short phrases. https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/kick%20the%20bucket

Comment: This is a request for resources, so I've voted to migrate to meta.

Comment: It's not exactly what you're looking for, but you should check out https://www.phrontistery.info/ to "find that half-remembered rare or obscure word you've been looking for, or to read and explore essays on language, linguistics, and culture."

Comment: [Collins Cobuild Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/throw), as well as giving the now usual list of synonyms, gives sentential definitions rather than synonym definitions. Here, << **throw**: VERB
When you throw an object that you are holding, you move your hand or arm quickly and let go of the object, so that it moves through the air. >>